# Multiple line and bar chart in ggplot with geom_text and colours

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I want to combine a line and a bar chart with three different variables using ggplot. The bar chart should have the values on top and should be filled with the same colours as the lines in the chart above. Here is my code

```
# First some data generation
df.x = data.frame(date = Sys.Date()-20:1,
                  value = c(1:20),
                  variable = "line",
                  object = "x")

df.y = data.frame(date = Sys.Date()-20:1,
                  value = c(1:20)*2,
                  variable = "line",
                  object = "y")

df.z = data.frame(date = Sys.Date()-20:1,
                  value = c(1:20)*3,
                  variable = "line",
                  object = "z")

df.y.bar = data.frame(date = Sys.Date()-10,
                  value = 30,
                  variable = "bar",
                  object = "y")

df.x.bar = data.frame(date = Sys.Date()-10,
                      value = 40,
                      variable = "bar",
                      object = "x")

df.z.bar = data.frame(date = Sys.Date()-10,
                      value = 50,
                      variable = "bar",
                      object = "z")

df = rbind(df.x, df.y,df.z, df.x.bar, df.y.bar,df.z.bar)

my.cols = c("blue", "green", "yellow")

# Pass everything to ggplot
ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "date", y = "value", fill="variable")) +  
  facet_grid(variable~., scales="free_y") + 
  geom_line(data = subset(df, variable == "line"), aes(colour = factor(object)), size = 1, show_guide = FALSE, stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(data = subset(df, variable == "bar"), aes(colour = factor(object)), show_guide = TRUE, stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(data = subset(df, variable == "bar"), aes(y=value+0.7 * sign(value), ymax=value, label=round(value, 2)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size=3) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = my.cols)
```

The resulting plot is not exactly what I wanted. I used `position_dodge(width = 0.9)` but the text over the bars does not move. Irretatingly this does not happen when I only chose two variable (e.g. x and y) to be included in the data frame. The desired result should look like this:

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Hi beetroot. It works with your data. I tried it on my data set and the colouring of the bars worked just fine. Unfortunately the text above the bars still doesn't move, even if i apply the group Argument...

Comment: Weird, can you post some data and the code to reproduce the text problem?

Comment: It will probably exceed the simplicity of the above example by far. Should I post the code anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You can fill the bars by choosing `fill = factor(object)` and adding `scale_fill_manual(values = my.cols)`. 
In order to have only one legend I think removing `fill="variable"` from `aes_string` did the trick in combination with `scale_fill_manual`. 
And for dodging the text you need to add a `group` argument and `position = position_dodge(width=1)`

```
ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "date", y = "value")) +  
          facet_grid(variable~., scales="free_y") + 
          geom_line(data = subset(df, variable == "line"), aes(colour = factor(object)), size = 1, show_guide = FALSE, stat="identity") +
          geom_bar(data = subset(df, variable == "bar"), aes(fill = factor(object)), show_guide = TRUE, stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
          geom_text(data =subset(df, variable == "bar"), aes(x=date, y=(value+0.7) * sign(value), ymax=value, label=round(value, 2), group=object), position = position_dodge(width=1), size=3) +
          scale_colour_manual(values = my.cols) +
          scale_fill_manual(values = my.cols)
```

[image]